# Moving our drupal site to https/SSL any tips

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

We are moving our entire Drupal site to SSL/https
Any tips/ suggestions? Like how to bulk 301 all urls  from http to https
or a check list we should prepare..

Thanks

Comment: Is this related to programming or more of an administration issue? If the former, please specify a problem, if the latter, you're on the wrong forum.

Comment: I do find such comments rather tiring. Yes, this may not be precisely a programming question but if, for example, an answer would require configuring a htaccess file, then that's as near programming for me as the dictionary definition. I think more important is how interesting is the question to the community and this one is exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a new httaccess rule in your .htaccess file. Have all links redirect to https to preserve url paths.

Comment: yes we have created new rule in htaccess with 301 redirect for all http to https. Apart from which any external resources fetched through http are now fetched through https eg. any third party javascripts